PXE boot kernel panic error
I have created initrd, vmlinuz, and filesystem.squashfs from a running custom Ubuntu 24 VM. I am attempting to use these initrd, vmlinuz, and filesystem.squashfs to PXE boot another server with this custom image. But I get this error:
[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200 ]

I did sudo update-initramfs -u before extracting the initrd.
My pxe configuration is:
:custom_ubuntu
set boot_server http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX/custom_ubuntu/boot

kernel ${boot_server}/vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img ip=dhcp boot=live toram=filesystem.squashfs console=ttyS0,11$
initrd ${boot_server}/initrd.img

boot

